# How would I make changes to an html string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm reading from an api that returns an html string. And I'm using knockout to bind that html to the content of a div.

What I want to do is make changes to the anchor elements in that string before I bind it.

For example let's say I get this as a response.

`"<div>Lorem ipsum <a href='#'>link1</a> more random text</div>"`

And I want to change the anchor text to something else.

This is what I'm trying right now

```
var htmlString = "<div>Lorem ipsum <a href='#'>link1</a> more random text</div>";
var links = $(htmlString).find("a");
$(links[0]).text("hello world");
$("#stringTarget").html(htmlString);
```

and it's not making the update.

**Note**: the example isn't using knockout.js, it's just to illustrate the process of editing a string then setting the html of a div to the altered string.

[Here is a fiddle of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8gWGY/)

Comment: You sent the original string to `stringTarget` rather than the jquery object you created and modified.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the link

Comment: @KevinB, yes I know.  I want to know how to update the original string with the new link data.  I can't just send the link as it would be missing the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like

```
var htmlString = $("<div>Lorem ipsum <a href='#'>link1</a> more random text</div>");
var links = $(htmlString).find("a").text("hello world");
$("#master").html(htmlString);
```

You should use `$()` to make it as an object

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3ucA/8/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks  It was just wrapping the original string with jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlString = "<div>Lorem ipsum <a href='#'>link1</a> more random text</div>";
var elems = $.parseHTML(htmlString);
$(htmlElements).children('a').text('my new text');
```

Comment: You should try to avoid code only answers. Add a description of what you changed and _why_ it was changed.

Comment: Noted and good suggestion. I'll keep that in mind for future answers.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is:

Instantiate `htmlString` anchor in var `links` (`htmlString` stay intact):

```
var links = $(htmlString).find("a");
```

and set text text to first anchor in var links (`htmlString` still stay intact):

```
$(links[0]).text("hello world");
```

Then, you are retrieving the original htmlString, which wasn't changed:

```
$("#stringTarget").html(htmlString);
```

Instead,

How about directly set it all in one line?

```
var htmlString = "<div>Lorem ipsum <a href='#'>link1</a> more random text</div>";
$("#stringTarget").html(htmlString).find("a").text("hello world");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8gWGY/1/